# How to Deserialize a Map into a Vector of Enums with Serde in Rust?

Tags: rust, yaml, serde

I am working on a Rust project where I need to deserialize YAML configuration data into a more structured Rust type. The YAML data represents output specifications for different data sinks (like CSV and JSON files) and looks something like this:

```
output_data_specs:
  csv:
    file_path: "/output-data.csv"
    delimiter: ","
  json:
    file_path: "/output/"
    another: "foo"
```

I want to deserialize this data into a Rust **`Vec<Sink>`**, where **`Sink`** is an enum that can represent either a CSV sink or a JSON sink:

```
pub enum Sink {
    Csv(CsvSink),
    Json(JsonSink),
}

pub struct CsvSink {
    file_path: String,
    append: bool,
}

pub struct JsonSink {
    file_path: String,
    another: String
}
```

I'm looking for a way to implement this with Serde, it should deserialize the map of output data specs map into a list of Sinks in something like:

```
pub struct InferenceConfig {
    pub name: String,
    pub output_data_specs: Vec<Sink>,
}
```

I'd preferably like to implement this without a custom deserializer.
Any examples or pointers to relevant documentation would be very helpful.

Comment: You can deserialize this as a map, and then transform it manually into a vec.

Comment: If I'm reading that right, I don't think it'd work. If you have duplicate keys, (eg json, csv, json) you'd lose all but one of them

Comment: @Holloway that's not valid yaml, anymore than it's valid json, though

Comment: That's true, @mtobin, should it be a sequence rather than a map?

Comment: @Holloway This is a good point. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change your Map to a List (simply add `-` in front of `csv` and `json`) — which it seems you want to do, since `output_data_specs` is a `Vec<Sink>` — you can use `#[serde(with = "serde_yaml::with::singleton_map_recursive")]` to use the keys `csv` and `json` as enum tags in serde’s default enum representation.

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "snake_case")]
pub enum Sink {
    Csv(CsvSink),
    Json(JsonSink),
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct CsvSink {
    file_path: String,
    append: bool,
    delimiter: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct JsonSink {
    file_path: String,
    another: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct InferenceConfig {
    pub name: String,
    #[serde(with = "serde_yaml::with::singleton_map_recursive")]
    pub output_data_specs: Vec<Sink>,
}

fn main() {
    let s = r#"
        name: "xyz"
        output_data_specs:
            - csv:
                file_path: "/output-data.csv"
                append: true
                delimiter: ","
            - json:
                file_path: "/output/"
                another: "foo"
        "#;
    let inference_config = serde_yaml::from_str::<InferenceConfig>(s).unwrap();
    println!("{inference_config:#?}");
}
```

```rust
InferenceConfig {
    name: "xyz",
    output_data_specs: [
        Csv(
            CsvSink {
                file_path: "/output-data.csv",
                append: true,
                delimiter: ",",
            },
        ),
        Json(
            JsonSink {
                file_path: "/output/",
                another: "foo",
            },
        ),
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`serde_with`'s `EnumMap`](https://docs.rs/serde_with/latest/serde_with/struct.EnumMap.html) is a perfect fit:

```rust
#[serde_with::serde_as]
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct InferenceConfig {
    pub name: String,
    #[serde_as(as = "serde_with::EnumMap")]
    pub output_data_specs: Vec<Sink>,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#[serde(untagged)]` for this

```
use std::collections::hash_set::Intersection;
use crate::Sink::{Csv, Json};
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct InferenceConfig {
    pub name: String,
    pub output_data_specs: Vec<Sink>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum Sink {
    Csv(CsvSink),
    Json(JsonSink),
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct CsvSink {
    file_path: String,
    append: bool,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct JsonSink {
    file_path: String,
    another: String,
}

fn main() {
    let config = InferenceConfig {
        name: "test".into(),
        output_data_specs: vec![
            Csv(CsvSink {
                file_path: "csv path".into(),
                append: true,
            }),
            Json(JsonSink {
                file_path: "json path".into(),
                another: "another string".into(),
            }),
        ],
    };

    let str = serde_yaml::to_string(&config).unwrap();
    eprintln!("{}", str);
    let config: InferenceConfig = serde_yaml::from_str(&str).unwrap();
    eprintln!("{:?}", config);
}
```

```
name: test
output_data_specs:
- file_path: csv path
  append: true
- file_path: json path
  another: another string

InferenceConfig { name: "test", output_data_specs: [Csv(CsvSink { file_path: "csv path", append: true }), Json(JsonSink { file_path: "json path", another: "another string" })] }
```

Answer (score 0):

@trust_nickol's answer shows one way to do it, but the type is no longer mentioned in the YAML. If you want to keep the explicit type, you  can:

- Use a YAML tag to specify the type:

  ```yaml
  name: test
  output_data_specs:
  - !CsvSink
    file_path: csv path
    append: true
  - !JsonSink
    file_path: json path
    another: another string
  ```
- Use an [internal tag](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#internally-tagged):

  - Add `#[serde (tag = "type")]` to your `enum`.
  - Add a `type` field to your YAML entries:

    ```yaml
    name: test
    output_data_specs:
    - type: CsvSink
      file_path: csv path
      append: true
    - type: JsonSink
      file_path: json path
      another: another string
    ```
- If you want to keep the exact YAML format from your question, you can do it if you deserialize through a wraper `struct` using [`deserialize_with`](https://serde.rs/variant-attrs.html#deserialize_with):

  ```rust
  #[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
  #[serde(untagged)]
  pub enum Sink {
      #[serde (deserialize_with = "sink::deserialize_csv")]
      Csv(CsvSink),
      #[serde (deserialize_with = "sink::deserialize_csv")]
      Json(JsonSink),
  }

  mod sink {
      pub fn deserialize_csv<'de, D: Deserializer<'de>> (d: D)
          -> Result<super::CsvSink, D::Error> where D: Deserializer<'de>
      {
          #[derive (Deserialize)]
          struct Wrapper { csv: super::CsvSink, }
          Wrapper::deserialize (d).map (|w| w.csv)
      }

      pub fn deserialize_json<'de, D: Deserializer<'de>> (d: D)
          -> Result<super::JsonSink, D::Error> where D: Deserializer<'de>
      {
          #[derive (Deserialize)]
          struct Wrapper { json: super::JsonSink, }
          Wrapper::deserialize (d).map (|w| w.json)
      }
  }

  #[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
  pub struct CsvSink {
      file_path: String,
      append: bool,
  }

  #[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
  pub struct JsonSink {
      file_path: String,
      another: String,
  }
  ```